# When is the css related xml file created and what's its use within Codename One css compiler?

Tags: css, codenameone

I am using the css compiler (formerly known as css plugin) in my CN1 project. I noticed that an xml file is generated sometimes in the project res/theme folder. If I delete it I noticed it is not automaticaly generated when launching the project in the simulator. I had to do it a bunch of times because otherwise the changes made in the css source file were not taken into account (the css.res file would not take the modifications into consideration). So I ended up deleting both css.xml and css.res files to force the "plugin" to recompile again the css source file.

So my question is threefold: when is the css.xml file generated, when (and for what purpose) is it created, and is there a more efficient way to force the "plugin" to recompile the css source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That XML file is created and used by the theme designer only.  It will automatically be created if you open the .res file inside the designer and "team mode" is on. [More on team mode here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/teamwork-and-other-things.html).

This XML file is not used in the simulator.  Only the .res file is.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I did not know about Team mode!  But if I open a second time the res file (there is already an xml file present) then the xml file will override the res file in the designer. That what should have confused me because I used to open the res file with the designer to check if the latest changes had been taken into account.

Comment: Yes that's intentional. That way if a team mate commits a change it overrides the locally outdated binary